# External hard-drive's FAT32 partition not recognized by Windows after size increase with gparted

Tags: windows, gparted, external-hdd

I had an external hard-drive with a fat32 partition (which I used for exchanging files between ubuntu and windows), some unallocated space, and a ext4 partition (which I used to backup my linux system).

I then used gparted to enlarge the fat32 partition to include the unallocated space. After that, the hard drive kept working well on ubuntu while on windows I get the message that `The drive is not accessible. The volume does not contain a recognized file system.`

Windows' Disk Management says that the drive's file system is RAW. I read around and the only way to solve this seems to reformat the partition, but since it works fine on ubuntu I would first like to understand:

1. What happened exactly?
2. Is there now way I can fix this without formatting?

Comment: you should have told us the partition size; I'm betting you stretched it beyond windoze's maximum fat32 size limit!  (2tb generally.. but format can reduce/increase this).   Anyway this is a windoze limitation; so possibly is off-topic here anyway.

Comment: DO NOT REFORMAT!

Comment: This article outlines a similar situation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2261358/a-volume-may-show-up-as-raw-in-disk-management-after-you-extend-the-pa

Comment: unfortunately the article describe a situation where 'the volume may show as "raw" in disk management. However, when you run chkdsk, the file system is shown as NTFS.'. In my case when I run chkdsk the filesystem is shown as RAW and chkdsk is not available.